# Section of the finite family of open sets

Tags: calculus, general-topology

So, I know that the definition of an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is :

Let $D$ be an non-empty subset of $\mathbb R^n$. The set $D$ is defined as open if and only if $\forall P_o \in D$ $\exists$ $B(P_o,r) : B(P_o,r) \in D$ , which means that $B(P_o,r)$ is inside D.

Now, how do we prove that the section of a finite family of open sets $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^d$ ? I can start by the definition :

Since we have a finite family of open sets, it means that :

$\forall A_i \subset \mathbb R^d$ we have that $A_i$ is an open subset and by definition we get that : $\exists $ $B_i(P_i,r_i) \forall P_i \in A_i \subset \mathbb R^d$ such that $B_i(P_i,r_i)$ is inside $\mathbb R^d$.

But after forming the definition, how do we prove the statement ? Can we say that we can see from the statement that since we have that there always exists an open ball for each open one, there is a wider open ball which is in $\mathbb R^n$ that includes all of the open balls of each open set in the family given ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost, but the other way around: You take the *minimum* ball radius, i.e., for given $P\in A$, we have (for each $i$) some $r_i>0$ such that $B(P;r_i)\subset A_i$. Let $r$ be the minimum of the $r_i$ (this is where finiteness is needed!). Then $B(P;r)\subseteq B(P;r_i)\subset A_i$ for all $i$, hence $B(P;r)\subset A$.

Comment: Yep, pretty solid ! Great answer, I was banging my head around to find a strict mathematical proof or form one but I just couldn't get that detail, thanks so much !